# Rails: Stripe on Heroku Stuck on Test Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I have Stripe set up on my app so that it works perfectly on `localhost` and Heroku in test mode.  I have since switched to live mode on Stripe, as well as updating my `stripe_api_key` and `stripe_publishable_key` using these steps from the [`Stripe` documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails):

```
heroku config:set PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_live_... SECRET_KEY=sk_live_...
```

I also did this with `stripe_api_key` and `stripe_publishable_key`, as I have seen that in other documentation and wanted to cover my bases.

I have the following in my `application.example.yml`:

```
stripe_api_key:
stripe_publishable_key:

production:
  stripe_api_key:
  stripe_publishable_key:

SENDGRID_USERNAME:
SENDGRID_PASSWORD:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
AWS_REGION:
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
S3_BUCKET_NAME:
```

And the `application.yml` has the corresponding information.  My `stripe.rb` looks like this:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.application.secrets.publishable_key,
  :secret_key      => Rails.application.secrets.secret_key
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Can anyone see why Stripe is still running on Test mode on the production server on Heroku?

Comment: Did you restart your server after setting those keys? `heroku restart -a your-app`

Comment: @AbM, yes.  I restarted the whole app several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of Figaro/`application.yml` altogether and restructuring my `secrets.yml` file to have the following structure for staging/production:

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
staging:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  stripe_api_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"] %>
  stripe_publishable_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>
  sendgrid_username: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
  sendgrid_password: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  stripe_api_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"] %>
  stripe_publishable_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>
  sendgrid_username: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
  sendgrid_password: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
```

After this everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

`heroku config:set PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_live_... SECRET_KEY=sk_live_...`

You're setting two ENV vars on your heroku environment, which will be accessible in rails as `ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']` and `ENV['SECRET_KEY']`.

You can also see what ENV variables you have set, access them, remove them, or change their values, by visiting your heroku dashboard, your app, and then `Settings` and clicking `Reveal Config Vars`.

You only need to define them in `stripe.rb`

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}
```

or if you want to use your secrets, changing this on your secrets.yml

```
production:
  stripe_api_key: <%= ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>
  stripe_publishable_key: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY'] %>
```

And leaving your stripe.rb as was before.

I would still change your ENV variable names to be more specific, like
`STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` & `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`.

Comment: I have `stripe_api_key: <%= ENV["stripe_api_key"] %>` and `stripe_publishable_key: <%= ENV["stripe_publishable_key"] %>` in the production section of my 'secrets.yml' and have verified via the heroku dashboard that these same names are paired with my live keys on Heroku.  Still in test mode.

Comment: try changing just your `stripe.rb`. And making sure it loads correctly when you set `Stripe.api_key` (just `puts` the contents). Also check what is being set on your rendered page as the publishable key by inspecting the source.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything either.  :(

Comment: So what's being set as those keys?  If you find that then you can just do a global search (assuming your text editor allows it) and see where you're setting those values, eventually figuring out where you're doing it wrong